# Проблема с API Одноклассники (ok.ru): ok.friends.get(..) ведёт к ошибке—AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, odnoklassniki-api, одноклассники

Не получается использовать библиотеку для Python, работающую с API ok.ru
https://github.com/alternativshik/python-odnoklassniki

В мануале на странице git указано:

```
import odnoklassniki

ok = odnoklassniki.Odnoklassniki(client_key, client_secret, access_token)
print ok.group.getInfo('uids'='your_group_id', 'fields'='members_count')
```

По аналогии выполняю со своими данными, с единственным различием, что т.к. выполняю на 3 версии python, видоизменяю функцию `print`.
Получаю ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "OK API.py", line 31, in <module>
    x = ok.friends.get(fid='571031948142')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/odnoklassniki/api.py", line 100, in __call__
    return self._get(self._method, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/odnoklassniki/api.py", line 67, in _get
    status, response = self._request(method, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/odnoklassniki/api.py", line 106, in _request
    for key, value in kwargs.iteritems():
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`api` написан для `python 2`. Ошибка возникает потому, что в `dict` для `python 3` нет метода `iteritems`, вместо него используется метод `items`.

Чтобы использовать `api` в `python 3` придется его поправить, либо в ручную, либо при помощи утилиты 2to3.

Например вот так:

```
2to3 -w python-odnoklassniki
```

Comment: Вот где собака зарыта)
А я уже спаял вертолет:
`a = session_key
b = secretsession_key
c = secret_key
d = app_key
e = App_ID
def send():
    y = [a, b, c, d, e]
    random.shuffle(y)
    print(y)
    aa = str(y[0])
    bb = str(y[1])
    cc = str(y[2])
    ok = odnoklassniki.Odnoklassniki(aa, bb, cc)
    x = ok.friends.get(fid='514404667374')
    print(x)
    return ok
while x == 1:
    time.sleep(0.05)
    try:
        rr = send()
        break
    except AttributeError:
        print('*')
        pass`
Который рандомит подстановку всех известных. Жесть. Спасибо вам

Comment: спасибо. надо так: `"python C:\Users\alexw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Tools\scripts\2to3.py -w C:\Users\alexw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\odnoklassniki\api.py"`